# Javascript append/remove elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one question. Is possible delete `<span>` element added with javascript append?

When i try remove added span then nothing happens.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SelectBoxData span').click(function(){
        var StatusID = this.id;
        var StatusIDSplit = StatusID.split("_");
        var StatusText = $('#SelectBoxData #' + StatusID).text();

        $("#SelectBox").append('<span id=' + StatusID + '>' + StatusText + '</span>');
        $("#SelectBoxData #" + StatusID).remove();

        InputValue = $("#StatusID").val();
        if(InputValue == ""){
            $("#StatusID").val(StatusIDSplit[1]);
        }
        else{
            $("#StatusID").val($("#StatusID").val() + ',' + StatusIDSplit[1]);
        }
    });

    $('#SelectBox span').click(function(){
                var StatusID = this.id;
        $("#SelectBox #" + StatusID).remove();
    });
});
</script>

<div id="SelectBoxBG">
    <div id="SelectBox"><div class="SelectBoxBtn"></div></div>
    <div id="SelectBoxData">
        <span id="StatusData_1">Admin</span>
        <span id="StatusData_2">Editor</span>
        <span id="StatusData_4">Test 1</span>
        <span id="StatusData_6">Test 2</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="StatusID" />
</div>
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: you cannot assign same ID to multiple elements in javascript.

Comment: FYI, `var StatusID = this.id;  $("#SelectBox #" + StatusID).remove();` will just select the same element which `this` already refers to. If you already have a reference to the element, you don't have to search for it again! This is much simpler: `$(this).remove()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can delete them. However, you can't add `click` event handlers to them before they exist. This code:

```
$('#SelectBox span').click(function(){
    var StatusID = this.id;
    $("#SelectBox #" + StatusID).remove();
});
```

will only add a `click` event handler to `<span>` elements inside of `#SelectBox` at the time the code is run (so, based on your provided HTML, zero elements). If you want the event handler to react to dynamically added elements then you need to use a technique called [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), using the `.on()` function:

```
$('#SelectBox').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).remove(); // equivalent to the code you had before
});
```